# Coherence of pressure and mass flow in a pipe

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure

What is the coherence of pressure and mass-flow in a horizontal pipe? Let's assume I have just one pipe with pressure = 1.5 bar at the input and through pressure-losses 1.2bar at the output. Is there a different mass-flow at the input & output? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: What's *"masslwo"*?

Comment: @ACuriousMind - if you read the entire question you would see the word "mass-flow" used a little lower down...

Comment: You may find it useful to consider if and how the concept of *mass conservation* applies to the fluid entering and leaving any complex closed assembly of rigid pipes, assuming steady state.

Answer (score 1):

If the fluid is incompressible and/or the pipe is flowing at steady state, then the mass inflow will equal the mass flow out.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Let's assume i connect several pipes --> then the pressure drops at a certain length to zero but i would still have the same massflow at all nodes?

Comment: The sum of the mass flows in the pipes will be constant.  If the flow is distributed between several pipes, the individual flows will adjust in such a way that the pressures between the beginning and end of each pipe satisfy a flow equation, and the total flow to the pipes is equal to the feed flow.

Comment: Thank you, but I mean if i connect them in series

Comment: @lars111: If you have several questions, it is best in this website to ask several questions separately one at a time, using the [ask question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) link. It may be better to just [ask](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) whichever *one* of the questions is most likely to unlock whatever is really puzzling you. It is almost always unproductive to attempt to refine a poorly phrased question by incrementally adding caveats in a long series of comments. Just my $0.02 worth.